# thousand separator in integer values

Tags: delphi

Hi I want to make thousand separator for integer values
I been tried on `format('%n',[total])` but not working, it says

> wrong argument on %n

also been trying currency format but the result is my country currency format
I just want to make 'total' is show as thousand separated

Comment: Please read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format) *n - Number. The argument must be a floating-point value.*

Comment: The format string `n` requires a floating point value. You pass an integer. Convert the value to floating point. For instance `total*1.0`. It would be much nicer if there was a way to do this without floating point.

Comment: I see, it requires floating value.. it's worked, but it show one digit of decimal, how I can remove it?

Comment: thanks @SirRufo for editing my question, sorry i'm new..

Comment: The documentation has also an answer for this `%.0n` and the linked answer (see first comment) also. Although you are a beginner here, you should be able to follow links and read :o)

Comment: @iratirul Did you read the answers at the dupe Q?

Comment: yes and thanks @DavidHeffernan ,sorry i didn't noticed that link it worked, thanks a lot. its look like `slabelfx3.Caption:=Format('%.0n',[total]);`